# Remove gap between table rows after setting visibility to hidden

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to conditionally hide rows within my mat-table. Some rows will be hidden, some will not. Between each row is a very small gap. However, when a row has been hidden, it leaves a slightly larger gap in its place. Is there a way that I can hide the row without this extra gap being present?

I have tried using css to set the display/visibility.

The html:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Header">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Header</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" {{row.title}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" [ngClass]="{'invisible': row.invisible}">
</table>
```

The css:

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

This leaves a larger gap (maybe by a couple pixels) between rows where a row has been collapsed in between them. I have tried to set display to none but this has the same effect.

Comment: Did you try `display:none`?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was referencing when I said I had tried to set the css display. I should have been more specific and said setting the display to none. It produced the same result, though.

Comment: Have you tried with [hidden] `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [hidden]="row.invisible"></tr>` ?

Comment: This produces the same result.

Comment: So, the only way is to use *ngIf, in order to not create at all the row. You can try that but not sure will work. `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" *ngIf="!row.invisible"></tr>`. If not you can splice the invisible row  from your datasource : ``his.datasource.splice(indexRowInvisible, 1);``

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz, so I will help you easily with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an *ngIf in order to not even render the row in the first place.

Comment: I thought about that but wasn't sure how to do it since I needed a property of the row. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: can you create a codesandbox to illustrate your problem with a fully working example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions, and i finally found it ! it's not as pure as i wanted, but it works fine :

The html:

```
<table *ngIf="isToDisplay" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #categorieQuestions>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: false"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" [ngClass]="{'invisible': !row.visible}"></mat-row>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="libelle-question">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Enjeu</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let question">
                    <div *ngIf="question.visible">
                        <strong>{{question.libelle}}</strong>
                        <div class="reponse-facultative" *ngIf="!question.obligatoire">(Réponse non obligatoire)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>              
        </table>
```

The css:

```
mat-row {
    height: fit-content !important;

    &.invisible {
        min-height: 0 !important;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

The trick is to set min-height to 0 !important in order not to have the blank gap you talked about ;)